# How to force distributed training in tensorflow to use more than 1 server?

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the official distributed training documentation but find that only 1 server is used in databricks ganglia

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))
```

outputs `2`

why is only one server in used ? When there is multiple (2) server available?

```
with strategy.scope():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
  ])

  model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Is there a way I can force the number of server to split work in training?

Comment: As you can see in the example you call model.compile outside scope.
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#use_tfdistributestrategy_with_keras_modelfit

Comment: sorry I link the wrong link, I did wrap compile inside scope